# Can I row this boat to the water's edge?

Tags: locative, connotations

Can a person in a rowboat, while he is in the middle of a lake, say "I am now going to row the boat to the water's edge"?

I can imagine a man in a boat, in the middle of a lake, looking towards the shore and saying:  "People on shore are carrying cargo to the water's edge". But I cannot imagine him saying "I will row this boat to the water's edge".

Is there an implied vantage point in this phrase?

Comment: Michael row the boat a-edge? I think not. An interesting observation--are there any parallels?

Comment: The edge is normally the outer boundary of something, but the expression "Politics, for liberals, stops at the water's edge"...  definitely suggests a land-based viewpoint. Strange.

Comment: No parallels come immediately to mind, but it's still my first cup of coffee.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YbsKWSo1tMo

Answer (score 2):

"Shore" would be more natural here. It would work from both sides:

> I am now going to row the boat to shore.
>
> People on land are carrying cargo to the shore.

"Shore" means "the land along the edge of a sea, lake, or other large body of water". So saying "people on shore" in the second sentence would mean the people are at the edge of the water. In reality, the people would be going back and forth between the shore and further inland to bring the cargo to the shore. So saying "on land" would make more sense.

As a native English speaker (Canada), I'd never say "I am now going to row the boat to the water's edge". It would technically be correct, and people would understand what you mean, but it would sound odd, since there is already a word meaning "water's edge".

Comment: True.  Alternatively, you would row to the bank.  Particularly if you were on  a river.